# Can the power rule be used for the integral $\int y^{y+2}dy$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is this the right way to solve the integral?

$$\int y^{y+2}dy = \int y^u du = \frac{y^{u+1}}{u+1} = $$ $$=\frac{y^{y+3}}{y+3}$$

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: You can use the power rule only when your exponent is $\neq -1$ and is a constant.

Comment: What is the source of this problem ? Was it just "made up" to ask the question. ?

Answer (score 1):

No because whenever you perform a $u$ substitution, all terms with the variable being replaced(in this case y) must be written in terms of $u$, so your correct integral would be
\begin{equation}
\int y^{y+2} dy = \int (u - 2)^u du
\end{equation}
which is not very different from your original result. I don't know if this problem has a solution(if $x^{x+2}$ has an antiderivative).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int{y^{y+2}dy}$$ does not have an elementary integral. Many functions don't have one like $\int\frac{sinx}{x}dx$